# Should I leave tips in Latvian hotels

Tags: hotels, tipping, latvia, riga

Should I leave tips in hotels in Latvia?
Each day I put 2-3 lats (about 4-6 dollars) on the table, but each evening I'm returning to the room I find money untouched.

This is my first country where tips are ignored.
May be, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear that the money are a tip rather than spare change? At any rate, if I'm happy with the service, I'd usually write a short thank-you note as well, or instead, of leaving cash.

Comment: There's a very good chance that the cleaning personnel doesn't understand English.

Comment: Normally the tips for cleaning staff are left on the pillow of your bed.  Money on the table may have simply been forgotten.

Comment: @mindcorrosive A thankyou note with cash in an envelope would be the most appropriate gesture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience of holidaying in Europe & North Africa, tips for chamber maids etc are given at the end of the holiday/stay and more often than not given directly by oneself to the chamber maid, rather than being left anywhere.

Money left on a table would almost certainly not be seen as tips for cleaning your room, as indicated in Karlson's comments.

(Hotel staff wouldn't dare touch money left on a table simply for implications of theft, their job is too precious to risk, beside it simply not the done thing (at least in Europe, North Africa & I'm certain most parts of the world). To be perfectly honest with you I have never actually heard of people leaving loose change, be it coins/ notes on a table indicating it is for chamber maids/cleaning staff).

**In terms of leaving a tip, you should definitely give it (unless you have grave reservations not to), they definitely expect it, even if they don't directly ask or hint at it. Wages are generally very low.**

The same would apply when tipping a so called "Bell Boy" (hotel porter)

Answer (score 11):

It depends on hotel, but usually you do not have to give tips. Leaving money on table is not considered as tip. It's not allowed to touch anything what belongs to customer - you.

If you are in small hotel, you can give tips to the personnel, if you meet them in person.

Comment: Why -1? This seems to be the only answer based on actual local experience and not on the North American notion that you must actively punish or reward service staff instead of simply paying for their work.

Comment: It is insane that the only answer by an actual Latvian - in fact, the only answerer who seems to have *been* to Latvia - is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Given the definition of [Tips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_%28gratuity%29) being gratuity for good services why not use that as a basis for whether or not you leave a tip?

While in United States, Canada and elsewhere tipping in restaurants is expected it is still optional, so if you like the service you leave more if you don't you may not leave anything, so while it may not be [expected by the hotel staff in Latvia](http://www.visitlatvia.lv/en/tipping) if you feel that you got good service I would leave a tip anyway.

If not for nothing just for not touching money left on the table.

Comment: I'm pretty OK with the concept of tipping, it's just that nobody wants my tips)))

Comment: @shabunc As I mentioned in my comments before.  On the table it's not tips.  Just forgotten money. :)

Comment: -1 Whatever people might say or write about tips, they are either unnecessary (most of Western Europe) or an essential part of the person's income (e.g. in the US). The notion that because, unlike in many other professions, that income is not agreed to in advance or paid by the employer would means it is perfectly acceptable not to pay someone for their work because you have some sort of objection about the “service” is absurd.

Comment: @Annoyed Don't get your comment at all.

Comment: Tipping in restaurants in US is not really optional in my experience.

Comment: @Rafal Since when?

Comment: I don't know regulations and laws exactly, whether the staff can be paid less then minimal wage, how it's all taxed and is it OK to include that in the bill. But it is much different from European tipping culture. I've had waitress in San Francisco point out to me that I gave less than 15% of tip, after misunderstanding whether the service charge was in the bill or not.

Comment: @Rafal That's between you and the waitress.  The issue is that tipped employees can receive fixed salary below the minimum wage but there is nothing in the law that says you have to give tips.  The customary amount is 15% but there is nothing requiring you to give that much or anything at all.

Comment: @Karlson Agreed. There is no law saying you have to tip. But the fact that waiters are commonly underpaid and expected to make that up in tips, puts "tipping in restaurants is expected" in different perspective. There is a difference in tipping culture in US and Europe (or Canada I assume). That's all.

Comment: @Rafal That still doesn't make it mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving a tip is a personal decision and on average I only leave a tip in about half of the places I stay.  When I do, I never leave it loose on the table as i was told the maid is not allowed to take it.  I use Merci Envelopes that I have bought online.  These are small red envelopes that I carry in my wallet and can personalise if necessary.  You could just leave a note, but I find the envelopes more stylish.